# Potential energy of an oscillating pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions, oscillators

The following question always confuses me. for an oscillating pendulum why the potential energy is given by:

$$V = mgL(1-\cos\theta)$$

Why not $$V = mgL\cos\theta$$

Is this a convention or there something logical behind it.

I appreciate any help

Comment: The potential energy is greater, not less, when the pendulum is higher (i.e., at greater $\theta$). So the cosine term must be negative, not positive. The additive constant is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

The gravitational potential energy lost appears as the potential energy of the pendulum (which periodically changes to kinetic energy and back), in accordance with conservation of energy.

[image]

As shown in the figure, the **change** in potential energy = $ mgh = mgL - mgLcos \theta = mgL(1- cos \theta)$

Whereas, $mgLcos \theta$ is the **final gravitational potential energy** with respect to ground, not change in potential energy.

<sub>I hope I clarified the confusion, but if you have any other doubt, feel free to ask in the comments</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Just a question, I am a little bit confused because we generally talk about potential energy not the change in potential energy!

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician We don't measure an absolute value of potential energy, but a difference. Even $mgh$ isn't the absolute potential energy of a point. It isn't usually explicitly stated, but it is approximated for the gravitational potential energy difference between that point and ground,(or any other reference point). Even $\frac {GMm}{R}$ isn't the absolute value - it is measured considering that the potential energy at infinity is zero, so it's the difference again between the potential energy at the concerned point and infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple explanation for this.Let's take the lowest point of the path of the pendulum at zero potential energy.Consider the position when bob is at angle $\theta$ from equilibrium position.Now the potential energy of Bob at this point has increased from zero to $mgL(1-cos\theta)$

[image]

Comment: My confusion is why the bottom point $p$ is chosen as a reference?

Comment: We can take potential energy zero at any point.But it will be easy if we take it zero at bottom most point.If we take p=0 at top most point then,it will be negative at bottom points and if we take it zero at any other point,it will become more complicated

Answer (score 0):

The ground is chosen as refrence for zero PE,then if the angle made by string from vertical is $\theta$ and length of string is $L$ then obviously the height of Bob from ground is $L(1-cos\theta)$. I cannot understand how you are reaching to $Lcos\theta $. Maybe the reference or sign convention is different